# How to link postcode to broader geographical area in the United Kingdom

Tags: geospatial, uk, programming, postal-code

I have a dataset of companies, where one of the variables is its postcode. I want to link this postcode to a broader geographical unit. I have shapes file that enables me to map such broader geographical units. But I am not sure how I can do the linking. Clearly, the latter has not way of understanding where postcodes are, so it seems the only way to do this is by actually having a file that links every single postcode to the geographical unit of interest (as it seems to be done for ZIP codes for the US, e.g. [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/929/is-there-a-tool-to-match-zip-codes-to-cities?rq=1) and [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10447/trying-to-link-zip-code-to-core-based-statistical-area)). Unfortunately, I have not found such dataset for the UK.

Is there another way to produce the link that I am looking for?

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postal-code+uk, HTH

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of open datasets which link a postcode to a "broader geographical unit". The best dataset for the purpose depends on which "broader geographical unit" you are after.

The below list should cover most of the more common requirements:

[ONS Postcode Directory](http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk)

- County
- Local authority
- Electoral ward
- Country
- Region
- Westminster parliamentary constituency
- European electoral region
- NUTS and LAU codes
- Census output areas
- Parish

[Ordnance Survey Open Names](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-open-names.html)

- Populated place
- Postcode district
- Region
- Country

[Wikipedia: List of postcode districts in the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postcode_districts_in_the_United_Kingdom)

- Post town

[Open Postcode Geo](https://www.getthedata.com/open-postcode-geo)

- Postcode area
- Postcode district
- Postcode sector
- Outcode
- Country

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need [OS Code-Point](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-open.html) which will map from PostCode to X, Y point, NHS authority and administrative unit codes.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! The [UK Data Service](https://borders.ukdataservice.ac.uk/pcluts.html) has files containing every single postcode and the broader geographical boundaries to which it belongs, including:

- Constituencies
- Wards
- Travel to work areas
- Parishes
- Local Educational Authority
- Local Health authorities
- European Electoral Regions
- Government Office Regions
- Standard Statistical Regions
- Census workplace zones

More details can be found in the [User Guides](https://borders.ukdataservice.ac.uk/ukborders/pcluts_download/prebuilt/pcluts/ONSPDUserGuide2015v1.pdf) (link for February 2015 edition).

Comment: This is the ONS Postcode Directory. Other datasets exist with additional geographical units which are not included in the ONS Postcode Directory, see my answer for more details.